# Атомарный метод Interlocked.Add

Tags: c#, atomic

По какой причине метод Interlocked.Add принимает только int? Чем double мешает при атомарности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы лежат в низкоуровневых деталях реализации этих конструкций операционной системой (просто нет реализации этих версий на уровне ОС/процессоров). Подробности можно почитать на английской версии сайта: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400465/why-is-there-no-overload-of-interlocked-add-that-accepts-doubles-as-parameters